# Derivative of Poisson that approximates Binomial

Tags: probability, integration

Instead of a standard urn ball problem, I have many urns and balls. *Many*. One might say, a continuum of balls $B$ and urns $U$.

The likelihood of a single urn having $x$ matches is, under the Poisson approximation of the binomial,

$$ P(x) = \frac{\exp\left(-\frac{B}{U}\right)\left(\frac{B}{U}\right)^x}{x!}$$

I am interested in integrating something of the sort

$$ \int P(x)\frac{1}{1+x} dx$$

However, I am not sure how to work with the factorial, as it is only defined for natural numbers. I don't have a strong background in this area, is there any "obvious" approach that one would do? Or is there perhaps another way to set up the urn ball problem as to work with densities?

Comment: What are "matches" in this context? I think you should say a bit more about the scenario you're considering. Are you simply putting a large number $B$ of balls into a large number $U$ of urns, independently uniformly randomly choosing an urn for each ball?

Comment: @joriki exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This pertains the regime $B \gg U$.**

Generally, for sufficiently large $x$, you can approximate the factorial using for example Stirling's approximation, i.e. $x! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi x} (x/e)^x$, see Wikipedia for more details.

There are thus opportunities to approximate the integral when $B \gg U$, because then atleast intuitively, the probability density function has most of its mass far away from $x \approx 0$. If you would like to formally prove that an approximation in this limit will result in neglible error though, that will require splitting the integral into two pieces (close to zero and far away) and then prove that the probability density function indeed does not have substantial mass near $x \approx 0$.