# Conditional Poisson Probability

Tags: probability

We are tossing balls randomly, uniformly and independently into urns. For a very large number of balls $B$ and urns $U$, the number of balls in each urn follows a Poisson probability. There are red and blue balls, $B_R + B_B = B$

Our hero is a specific urn $u$. Let $b(k)$ indicate the likelihood of $k$ number of balls in our hero, and $b_r(k)$ indicate the likelihood of $k$ red balls in our hero. Let's call the corresponding realizations $\tilde b$ and $\tilde b_r$. I know that
$$ b(k) = f(k, B/U)\\
b_b(k) = f(k, B_b/U)
$$

I am after the probability of having $0$ red balls, conditional on having $y$ balls. That is $Prob(\tilde b_r = 0 | \tilde = y)$.

I tried

$$ Prob(\tilde b_r = 0 | \tilde b = y) = \frac{ Prob(\tilde b_r = 0 \cap \tilde b = y}{Prob(\tilde b = y)} \\
= \frac{ Prob(\tilde b_r = 0 \cap \tilde b = y)}{f(k, B/U)} \\
$$

But I have a problem with the numerator, as the two terms are clearly not independent. What's the way to approach this issue?

Comment: Related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1414605.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume that since you specified that there is a "very large number of balls", you're interested in an approximation that's valid for a very large number of balls.

If there is a very large number of balls, the colours of the balls are approximately independent, since putting one red ball into an urn approximately doesn't change the ratio of red to blue balls.

Thus in this approximation an urn known to contain $y$ balls corresponds to $y$ Bernoulli experiments with probability $p=B_B/B$ of each ball being blue, so the probability of no ball being red, i.e. all balls being blue, is approximately

$$
\left(\frac{B_B}B\right)^y\;.
$$

The precise probability, without approximation, is

$$
\frac{\binom{B_B}y}{\binom By}=\frac{B_B!(B-y)!}{B!(B_B-y)!}\;.
$$

Comment: What is the way to arrive to your second expression? I'll try to arrive there myself assuming Poisson instead of Bernoulli draws.

Comment: @FooBar: Given that there are $y$ balls in the urn, every selection of $y$ balls from the total of $B$ balls is equally likely. There are $\binom By$ such selections, and $\binom{B_B}y$ of them contain no red balls.